# How do you obtain a SvnLogEventArgs childs revision number in SharpSVN?

Tags: c#, children, sharpsvn, revisions

I have been working with SharpSVN quite a bit lately and I'm currently trying to obtain all of a revisions children's revision numbers. I see that using `SvnLogEventArgs.HasChildren` I can verify that they exist but it need the actual numbers of the children below it. I've been looking at the SvnClient object and see a `GetMergesMerged()` but an unable to determine what to feed it to return it the correct values, right now it does not return anything.

```
System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<SvnMergesMergedEventArgs> logitems = null;
SvnTarget target = SvnTarget.FromUri(new Uri(myRepoURL));
SvnUriTarget targetUri = new SvnUriTarget(new Uri(myRepoURL), revision);
client.GetMergesMerged(target, targetUri, out logitems);
```

This is what I currently use but is not returning anything, if someone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. -Thanks

Comment: "a revisions children's revision numbers", can you indicate, maybe with an example, what you mean here?

Comment: @ Sander Rijken Sorry for the delayed response, it seems as though the url changed and I wasn't seeing any of the updates on this post:

What I would like is similar to how TurtoiseSVN chains down merged revisions using the 'Include merged revisions'. So even if a revision to a file in the current url was changed else ware I will still be able to backtrack that file to where it was originally.

Comment: What command do you execute in TortoiseSvn to see that chain? Log/history?

Comment: @Sander Rijken Oh Yes, it is under 'Show Logs', then you check the 'Include Merged Revisions'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you want, you should use the `Log` (or `GetLog`) method.

```
Client.Log(new Uri(myRepoUrl),
    new SvnLogArgs
    {
        Start = startRevision,
        End = endRevision,
        Limit = numberOfItemsToFetch,
        RetrieveMergedRevisions = true
    },
    (s, e) =>
    {
        // e.MergeLogNestingLevel indicates if this is the first, second or nth level merge
    });
```

As with every SharpSvn call that takes a delegate, if you want to use the eventargs outside of the delegate, be sure to call `e.Detach()` inside the delegate/lambda

Comment: Okay I think I see, I actually currently use the RetrieveMergedRevisions so I'm not sure why I didn't see this before, I've actually had all the information to determine the NestingLevel but was trying to do it on a Revision->Revision basis and not looking at the big picture. Thanks.

Comment: `GetMergesMerged` is to check what revisions have been merged between source and target, so it will only contain the merged revisions, not the normal ones

Comment: I see, I was confused on why there were multiple Targets one being source and the other being target, that makes a lot more sense now, The API documentation doesn't explain much so I often have to test through and try and infer what each class method is doing. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @SamF: so how did you get the child revision numbers?